# problem when restoring postgresql database for a django application

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to transfer my testing server's database to my working PC. So I do this:

(Postgres 12.5)
`pg_dump -U nutrition -d mednutrition_db --clean -f mednut_bak.sql`

and then I try to restore it like this on my Postgres 9.5

`psql -U chris mednutrition_db < mednut_bak.sql`

This simple method was working fine for me. But now it seems there is a problem which I cannot solve.

I noticed that postgres creates (django)ID fields using this default value (for example):

`nextval('django_migrations_id_seq'::regclass)`

However, when I restore the database, the default value for the ID fields remains empty, and of course I cannot insert any new data to the restored database.

How can I resolve this?

UPDATE: I just noticed that on my backup file (mednut_bak.sql) there is the proper instruction to create the default ID sequence:

`ALTER SEQUENCE public.django_migrations_id_seq OWNED BY public.django_migrations.id;`

and

`ALTER TABLE ONLY public.django_migrations ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.django_migrations_id_seq'::regclass);`

So, I guess problem is while restoring because for some reason Postgres ignores these lines.

Comment: `nextval('django_migrations_id_seq'::regclass)` is something Postgres does, not Django. I'm guessing the issue is this; the dump is `-U nutrition`, the restore `-U chris`. Pretty sure if you look at the logs and/or the errors during the restore you will find `chris` does not have full privileges on all objects and those objects are being skipped.

Comment: trhanks. I changed that. I am also inclined to look somewhere in the user permissions. I just didn't have any problems before with similar user combinations in other projects. I will look deeper into it and let you know.

Comment: Hello. I had the same issue. The only fix for me was using a newer version on my local postgres. I upgrated to 11 and it worked. For some reason, the 9.5 version ignores the sequence creation.

Comment: Maybe its something related to ownership that was changed on newer versions.